# Is there a site that ranks comic runs by popularity, critical votes, etc?

Tags: comics

When I am looking for new anime series to try, I often use [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com.au/encyclopedia/ratings-anime.php) to pick by popularity or quality of votes. Because I haven't watched a whole lot of anime, it's useful to pick out series that I may not have heard of due to age, etc, but that I might enjoy.  It is a similar concept with [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/) for movies.

I was wondering whether any similar websites exist for ranking comic runs by popularity/voting?  Comparing, for example, Joss Whedon's run on Uncanny X-Men vs Batman's The Killing Joke vs Watchmen vs Sandman by user voting in some form.

Answer (score 1):

[Joss Whedon's run on Uncanny X-Men](http://www.comicvine.com/astonishing-x-men-by-joss-whedon-john-cassaday-astonishing-x-men-by-joss-whedon-john-cassaday-ultimate-collection/37-305838/) vs [Batman's The Killing Joke](http://www.comicvine.com/batman-the-killing-joke-the-killing-joke/37-119383/) vs [Watchmen](http://www.comicvine.com/watchmen-watchmen/37-184078/) vs [Sandman](http://www.comicvine.com/sandman-/37-268089/) on [ComicVine](http://www.comicvine.com/).

> ### What is Comic Vine's mission?
>
> Put simply, to be the most useful and easy to use comic book website in the world. We've also built enough community tools to hopefully be a fun place to kill time while you wait for the latest comic drop.
>
> <strike>Comic Vine is run by WhiskeyMedia. Collectively, we run Giant Bomb, Anime Vice, Comic Vine, Screened and Tested.</strike>

Comment: That last paragraph is out of date.  They're no longer owned by Whiskey Media.  They and Giant Bomb are now part of CBSi.

Comment: @Keen then their website [lies](http://www.comicvine.com/help/)!